# Django Heroku unable to verify first certificate

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, certificate, credentials

I am trying to deploy my django webapp on heroku. But when I try to login with Heroku credentials, It gives me the error : Unable to verify first certificate.

```
(myDjangoEnv) C:\Python27\WebsiteWithDjango\DjangoStuff\mproj>heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: changaikwad@gmail.com
Password: ************
Error: unable to verify the first certificate

(myDjangoEnv) C:\Python27\WebsiteWithDjango\DjangoStuff\mproj>
```

I tried many solutions online and also those available here but still I am not getting past this. I tried updating pip. Uninstalling heroku and reinstalling it but still no luck. Please help.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Python 2.7?

Comment: @Deesha No its Python 3.6

Comment: `cd /Applications/Python\ 3.6/

 ./Install\ Certificates.command` 
Try running this command

Comment: @Deesha Thanks for the answer. But I have installed python 3.6 through Anaconda distribution. Will this command work in this case as well?